# Option menu in Android

Tags: android, optionmenu

I am new to developing Android apps.

I would like to add a settings option menu. The requirement for the app is that when you click `settings` in the option menu the screen will show a sentence `Add beep after ___ counts.`

How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

Its on the OnCreateOptions and OnOptionsItemSelected, Plus you need to manipulate the menu folder / menu xml also. Try to read about them and instantiating them is as easy as a switch case, as well as for the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate activity/fragment to handle `Add beep after ___ counts`

Here is the flow, read a little bit more on these.  You can find lot of examples on each of these:

1. Create Main Activity with a menu.xml that has a settings action
2. Create another activity or a dialog fragment with a layout of
   `<textview> <edittext> <textview>`.  This is to show the `Add beep
   after ___ counts`.  In MainActivity, on menu action "settings", show this fragment.
3. You can save the count persistently using preferences

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

mainmenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings_label"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Add beep after ___ counts.", duration).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

For more information read this [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)